# List Experiments as Right-Truncated Poisson?

Tags: poisson-distribution, experiment-design, truncation

## A common scenario for the analysis of list experiments:

Note: the standard list experiment is also known as the Item Count Technique (see Imai 2011: http://imai.princeton.edu/research/list.html)

1. Respondents are randomly assigned to a control ($T_c$) or treatment ($T_t$) group.
2. Those in $T_c$ are presented a list of $k$ items. Those in $T_c$ report the number $y_c$ of items meeting some arbitrary criteria $z$.
3. Those in $T_t$ are presented a list of $k+1$ items, where the first $k$ items are the same as the list those in $T_c$ view. Those in $T_t$ report the number $y_t$ of items meeting the same criteria $z$.
4. Analysts are interested in some quantity such as $E[ E[y_t] - E[y_c]]$, i.e. the expected difference in expected counts $E[k]$ between $T_t$ and $T_c$.

   - They might adopt a regression framework where  $k_i = \alpha + \beta_1T_i$ and interpret $\beta_1$ as the average treatment effect (ATE) of viewing $k+1$ items rather than $k$ items. This is further interpreted as the expected proportion of respondents reporting the extra item $T_t$ saw meets criteria $z$.

## Questions

(a)  Given that the dependent variable is bound on the interval $[0,$ $k+1]$, is it best to think of the outcome as a right-truncated count response? This is unclear because I tend to view truncation in terms of latent variables but I am not sure how to think of latency in list experiment responses.

(b) We know that $\beta_1 \in [0, 1]$ because $(k+1) - k = 1$ and $k - k$ = 0. I am unfamiliar with Bayesian statistics, is there a way to use this prior in a frequentist approach - given that we know with certainty the coefficient is bounded?

(c) Oftentimes the list experiment occurs in a complex design survey. Has anyone seen an R package to estimate truncated count models with clustering/stratification?